# CopyToDataTable Method - ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, linq

I get this error, at the CopyToDataTable method.

ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Following the procedure from - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
public DataTable GetAllRecords()
  {
    try
     {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       IEnumerable<DataRow> query = ((from p in MedianDB.tblCountries
                  select p).OrderBy(p => p.CountryName)) as IEnumerable<DataRow>;
       query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>(dt,LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
       return dt;                
     }
   catch (Exception ex)
     {
       throw ex;
     }
  }
```

using .Net Framework 4.0,Entity Data Model

Comment: The MSDN link says `How to: Implement CopyToDataTable<T> Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow`. Yours is a `DataRow`.

Comment: Yeah... my first guess is that the `as IEnumerable<DataRow>` is resulting in a null value assigned to `query`.  If you use a cast instead of `as`, you'll get a cast exception if the type isn't actually what you're expecting.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve here?  Is a DataTable better than the raw result of your from/select/orderby?  Some more context might help us find you a better answer.  Also, the specific type of `MedianDB.tblCountries` would help.

Comment: I just want to return a datatable. The GetAllRecords is a generic function I use for many forms, so CopyToDataTable method would be easy for me...How can I now change my linq to use copytodatatable

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is pretty straight forward. You're getting an `ArgumentNullException` and that's [documented as such](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359707%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The source IEnumerable sequence is null or the destination DataTable is null.

We know that `dt` isn't `null` so this means that the issue is you're `query` is `null`. So to fix it you should be able to leverage the `AsEnumerable` extension:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = (from p in MedianDB.tblCountries
                              select p)
                             .OrderBy(p => p.CountryName)
                             .AsEnumerable();
query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>(dt,LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
```

You can't just cast the result you were getting as an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, you need to *make it an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.* This code, `as IEnumerable<DataRow>`, was giving you a `null`.

---

And just an FYI, this `catch` is actually worse than just letting it throw because you're losing the stack trace in the process:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Just get rid of the `try/catch` all together if you're not really going to handle it.